# jQuery is not animating div in the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a problem with jQuery animate, I want to animate a few elements in one time. It is animating .top-left-lang first and then all flags. It need to be animated in same time, because it looks wrong...

Thanks in advance!

Sample of my code can be found here (please click first flag): http://vps274433.ovh.net/zadanie/OOstende/index.html

Here is my code:

```
<div class="background-black"></div>
<div class="top-left-lang">
    <div class="flag1"></div>
    <div class="flag2"></div>
    <div class="flag3"></div>
    <div class="flag4"></div>
    <div class="flag5"></div>
    <div class="flag6"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="chest">
        <div class="heart left side top"></div>
        <div class="heart center">&hearts;</div>
        <div class="heart right side"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

```js
var flagwidth = '-=184px';
var flagheight = '-=184px';
var click_check = false;

$( ".flag1" ).click(function() {
    if (click_check == false){
        click_check = true;

        $( ".flag1" ).css("opacity", "1");
        $( ".top-left-lang" ).css("margin-top", "20px");
        $( ".top-left-lang" ).css("margin-left", "20px");

        $( ".background-black" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
        $( ".top-left-lang" ).css("padding", "5px");
        $( ".flag1" ).css("margin-right", "2px");
        $( ".flag2" ).css("margin-right", "2px");
        $( ".flag3" ).css("margin-right", "2px");
        $( ".flag4" ).css("margin-right", "2px");
        $( ".flag5" ).css("margin-right", "2px");
        $( ".flag6" ).css("margin-right", "2px");

        $(".top-left-lang").animate({
            height: '-=182px',
            width: '-=1140px',
            top: '0',
            left: '0'
        }, { duration: 500, queue: false });

        $(".flag1").animate({
            height:flagheight,
            width:flagwidth
        }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $(".flag2").animate({
            height:flagheight,
            width:flagwidth
        }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $(".flag3").animate({
            height:flagheight,
            width:flagwidth
        }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $(".flag4").animate({
            height:flagheight,
            width:flagwidth
        }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $(".flag5").animate({
            height:flagheight,
            width:flagwidth
        }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
        $(".flag6").animate({
            height:flagheight,
            width:flagwidth
        }, { duration: 500, queue: false });
    }
});
```

```css
@import url('reset.css');

body{
    background-color:#2C2D32;
}

.container
{
    margin-top:300px;
}

.background-black
{
    z-index:5;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
}
.top-left-lang
{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:calc(50% - 680px);
    height:200px;
    width:1320px;
    margin-top:calc(50vh - 400px);
    background-color:#1B1C20;
    color:white;
    border:white 2px solid;
    padding:20px;
    border-radius:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.flag1
{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border-radius:200px;
    background:url('../img/pl.png');
    background-size:100%;
    opacity:0.7;
    transition: .5s;
}

.flag1:hover
{
    opacity:1;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.flag2
{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:url('../img/uk.png');
    background-size:100%;
    opacity:0.7;
    transition: .5s;
    border-radius:200px;    
}

.flag2:hover
{
    opacity:1;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.flag3
{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:url('../img/fr.png');
    background-size:100%;
    opacity:0.7;
    transition: .5s;
    border-radius:200px;    
}

.flag3:hover
{
    opacity:1;
    cursor:pointer;
}


.flag4
{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:url('../img/be.png');
    background-size:100%;
    opacity:0.7;
    transition: .5s;
    border-radius:200px;    
}

.flag4:hover
{
    opacity:1;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.flag5
{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:url('../img/ru.png');
    background-size:100%;
    opacity:0.7;
    transition: .5s;
    border-radius:200px;    
}

.flag5:hover
{
    opacity:1;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.flag6
{
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:url('../img/ro.png');
    background-size:100%;
    opacity:0.7;
    transition: .5s;
    border-radius:200px;    
}

.flag6:hover
{
    opacity:1;
    cursor:pointer;
}

/* Serce */

@-webkit-keyframes beat {
    0% {-webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(225deg); -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 40px rgba(213,9,60,1);}
    50% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(225deg); -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 70px rgba(213,9,60,0.6);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(225deg); -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 40px rgba(213,9,60,1);}
}
@-moz-keyframes beat {  
    0% {-moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(225deg); -moz-box-shadow:0 0 40px rgba(213,9,60,1);}
    50% {-moz-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(225deg); -moz-box-shadow:0 0 70px rgba(213,9,60,0.6);}
    100% {-moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(225deg); -moz-box-shadow:0 0 40px rgba(213,9,60,1);}
}
@keyframes beat {  
    0% {transform: scale(1) rotate(225deg); box-shadow:0 0 40px #d5093c;}
    50% {transform: scale(1.1) rotate(225deg); box-shadow:0 0 70px #d5093c;}
    100% {transform: scale(1) rotate(225deg); box-shadow:0 0 40px #d5093c;}
}

#background {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: #ffa5a5;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffa5a5 0%, #ffd3d3 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffa5a5), color-stop(100%,#ffd3d3));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffa5a5 0%,#ffd3d3 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #ffa5a5 0%,#ffd3d3 100%);
}
#chest {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:450px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.heart {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg,  #F50A45 0%, #d5093c 40%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right 50%, left 50%, color-stop(0%,#F50A45), color-stop(40%,#d5093c));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg,  #F50A45 0%,#d5093c 40%);
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg,  #F50A45 0%,#d5093c 40%);
    -webkit-animation: beat 0.7s ease 0s infinite normal;
    -moz-animation: beat 0.7s ease 0s infinite normal;
    animation: beat 0.7s ease 0s infinite normal;
}
.heart.center {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #B80734 0%, #d5093c 40%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#B80734), color-stop(40%,#d5093c));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #B80734 0%,#d5093c 40%);
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg,  #B80734 0%,#d5093c 40%);
}
.heart.top {
    z-index:3;
}
.side {
    top:50px;
    width:220px;
    height:220px;
    -moz-border-radius: 220px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 220px;
    border-radius: 220px;
}
.center {
    width:210px;
    height:210px;
    bottom:100px;
    left:145px;
    font-size:0;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
.left {
    left:62px;
}
.right {
    right:62px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove `animate` when changing `.flags` properties and change it without any `animation` because it is already has animation on its style
for example use

```
$(".flag1").css({
    height:flagheight,
    width:flagwidth
});
```

instead of

```
$(".flag1").animate({
    height:flagheight,
    width:flagwidth
},500);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/udm86reh/

```
var flagwidth = '-=184px';
var flagheight = '-=184px';
var click_check = false;

$( ".flag1" ).click(function() {

  if(click_check == false){
    click_check = true;

    $( ".flag1" ).css("opacity", "1");
    $( ".top-left-lang" ).css("margin-top", "20px");
    $( ".top-left-lang" ).css("margin-left", "20px");

    $( ".background-black" ).fadeOut( "slow" );
    $( ".top-left-lang" ).css("padding", "5px");
    $( ".flag1" ).css("margin-right", "2px");
    $( ".flag2" ).css("margin-right", "2px");
    $( ".flag3" ).css("margin-right", "2px");
    $( ".flag4" ).css("margin-right", "2px");
    $( ".flag5" ).css("margin-right", "2px");
    $( ".flag6" ).css("margin-right", "2px");


    $(".top-left-lang").animate({
      height: '-=182px',
      width: '-=1140px',
      top: '0',
      left: '0'
    }, 500);
    $(".flag1").css({
      height:flagheight,
      width:flagwidth
    });
    $(".flag2").css({
      height:flagheight,
      width:flagwidth
    });
    $(".flag3").css({
      height:flagheight,
      width:flagwidth
    });
    $(".flag4").css({
      height:flagheight,
      width:flagwidth
    });
    $(".flag5").css({
      height:flagheight,
      width:flagwidth
    });
    $(".flag6").css({
      height:flagheight,
      width:flagwidth
    });

  }

});
```

Comment: Had no idea that animate is for next operations aswell... thank you so much! It works

Comment: the `.flag` elements do not take the animations of the parent. The reason the reason why the animation is applied is because each `.flag` has the `transition: .5s;` in their style. It has nothing to do with the parent element. @KarolGasienica (The shown solution is correct and works, but the explanation is wrong)

Comment: @t.niese  you are right I explained it in a wrong way :)) Thank you for your note, I did this edit to my answer :))

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you combine css transitions and jQuery animation.

You set `transition: .5s;` for all of your flags, so the transition time applys to all css properties including the `height` and `width` you try to animate with jQuery. You need to make your `transition: .5s;` specific to only use it with your `opacity`: `transition: opacity .5s`. Or don't use the jQuery animation at all and stay with css only transitions.

Beside that you repeat to much of your code over and over again:

E.g. with your animation either use one common class `flag` or write:

```
$(".flag1, .flag2, .flag3, .flag4, .flag5, .flag6").animate({
        height:flagheight,
        width:flagwidth
}, { duration: 500, queue: false });
```

The same with with your css code.